# Neighbourhood filter of an isolated point of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, filters

How can I prove this?

> Let $(X,\tau)$ a topological space, and $x \in X$. Then the neighbourhood filter $\mathcal{V}(x)$ is an ultrafilter if and only if $x$ is an isolated point of $X$

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** If $\mathcal V(x)$ is an ultrafilter then either $\{x\}$ is in $\mathcal V(x)$ or it isn't. Can it *not* be there? Also, recall that if $A\in\mathcal V(x)$ then there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq A$.

The other direction is much simpler, and you should probably be able to figure it out on your own.